# openerp filtering data by on-change field

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

In openeducat module, while generating timetable I want to load subjects filtered by faculty. This is the cord which I have tried.

```
class generate_time_table_line(osv.osv_memory):
    _name = 'gen.time.table.line'
    _description = 'Generate Time Table Lines'
    _rec_name = 'day'

    _columns = {
        'gen_time_table': fields.many2one('generate.time.table', 'Time Table', required=True),
        'faculty_id': fields.many2one('op.faculty', 'Faculty', required=True),
        'subject_id': fields.many2one('op.subject', 'Subject', required=True),
        'day': fields.selection([('1', 'Monday'),
                             ('2', 'Tuesday'),
                             ('3', 'Wednesday'),
                             ('4', 'Thursday'),
                             ('5', 'Friday'),
                             ('6', 'Saturday'),
                             ('7', 'Sunday'), ]
                            , 'Day', required=True),
        'period_id': fields.many2one('op.period', 'Period', required=True),
    }
```

function......

```
def onchange_faculty(self, cr, uid, ids, faculty_id, context=None):
    values = {'faculty_subject_ids': False}
    faculty = self.pool.get('op_faculty').browse(cr, uid, id(faculty_id), context=context)
    values['faculty_subject_ids'] = faculty.faculty_subject_ids
    return {'value': values}
```

and this is the field in xml

```
<field name="faculty_id" on_change='onchange_faculty(faculty_id, context)'/>
```

while changing faculty I got this error

```
2015-02-05 06:41:59,207 4104 ERROR myschool openerp.osv.osv: Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Development\MySchool_New\Source\trunk\openerp.myschool\server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Development\MySchool_New\Source\trunk\openerp.myschool\server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "E:\Development\MySchool_New\Source\trunk\openerp.myschool\server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "E:\Development\MySchool_New\Source\trunk\openerp.myschool\src\myschool\wizard\generate_time_table.py", line 156, in onchange_faculty
faculty = self.pool.get('op_faculty').browse(cr, uid, id(faculty_id), context=context)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'browse'

2015-02-05 06:41:59,233 4104 ERROR myschool openerp.netsvc: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'browse'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Development\MySchool_New\Source\trunk\openerp.myschool\server\openerp\netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "E:\Development\MySchool_New\Source\trunk\openerp.myschool\server\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "E:\Development\MySchool_New\Source\trunk\openerp.myschool\server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "E:\Development\MySchool_New\Source\trunk\openerp.myschool\server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Development\MySchool_New\Source\trunk\openerp.myschool\server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "E:\Development\MySchool_New\Source\trunk\openerp.myschool\server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "E:\Development\MySchool_New\Source\trunk\openerp.myschool\src\myschool\wizard\generate_time_table.py", line 156, in onchange_faculty
faculty = self.pool.get('op_faculty').browse(cr, uid, id(faculty_id), context=context)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'browse'
2015-02-05 06:41:59,293 4104 INFO myschool werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Feb/2015 06:41:59] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

How can I solve this problem...?

Answer (score 0):

onchange is wrong. try with this code:

```
def onchange_faculty(self, cr, uid, ids, faculty_id, context=None):
    values = {}
    if faculty_id:
        faculty = self.pool.get('op.faculty').browse(cr, uid, faculty_id, context=context)
        if faculty.faculty_subject_ids:
            values['faculty_subject_ids'] = faculty.faculty_subject_ids
    return {'value': values}
```

Comment: This time I got this error.

XmlHttpRequestError INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>

Comment: it's a server error and not related with this code. Might be you need to restart your postgres server after than it will work

Comment: it tells like this:         raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: browse_record(op.subject, 1) is not JSON serializable

Comment: `faculty_subject_ids` field must be on `generate_time_table_line` class than and than we can update it value on return values of onchange. So add filed and than try above code.